# mysql with subquery on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

i have a single mysql table with at minimum userId, wager.
Data can be

```
userId = 1 wager = 10.00, userId = 2 wager = 5.00, userId = 3 wager = 1.00.
```

I want to run a select with a userId param that returns all userId's that are `<=` the wager for that user
So if `userId = 2` I get back all other users with a wager of 5.00 or less.
Query does a lot more than this with one join but just need some help or best approach with the above

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with a self-join:

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM user AS u1
INNER JOIN user AS u2 ON u1.wager <= u2.wager
WHERE u2.userId = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userA.*
FROM user AS userA,user AS userB 
WHERE userA.wager <= userB.wager 
AND userA.userId=userB.userId
AND userB.userId = 2
```

It's a good question and hope it helps you. I think most people forgot to link the userId together and it may need to link the userId together.